# Using regression tree on time series data

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, cart

I have been looking around for resources on applying a regression tree in an attempt to understanding how various spend variables impact a companies revenue overtime. Is this type of analysis something that a regression tree can do? I'm not aware of the assumption that one would be making by applying a regression tree to time series data, are there any?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can apply a regression tree to time-series (most of the time). The most simple thing you can do is feed it a window and train it to predict the last value.

Assumptions in this case: you assume that the process that generated the time-series is stationary and has a markov property (the size of your window).

You can relax these assumptions by mixing features into the window.

Comment: Ok thats good to know. Is there a way to then use the tree to make recommendations on spending among the various spend variables?

Comment: Yes, just feed it the same data, except for the value you're trying to predict, and it will make a prediction